# Pass string to QueryMap with spaces

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

This is the @GET request

```
@GET("restful/api/search")
suspend fun librariesSearchBook(
    @Header("Authorization") access_token: String,
    @QueryMap(encoded = true) fData: Map<String, String>,
    @Query("term") term:String,
    @Query("page") page:Int,
):Response<SearchBooksResponse>
```

and this is function

```
 fun facetLibrariesSpinnerItem(facetId:String?,item:String?,term: String){
    viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO ){
        val user = dataManager.getUser()
        val mapValue = mutableMapOf<String,String>()
        mapValue.put("f[0]", "$facetId:$item")

        try{
            val response = librarySearch.librariesSearchBook(user.access_token,mapValue,term,searchPageIndex)
            if(response.isSuccessful){
                    print(response)
            }

        }catch (exception: Exception){
            print(exception.message)
        }
    }
}
```

QueryMap contain $item which have spaces like "Name: Hashir Hamza" I want to sent it same as to api but it convert space into %20 like Name:%20Hashir%20Hamza. and

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html

Comment: @Raghunandan I did encoded =true but it still convert space to %20

Comment: what does it show at the api side. its looks fine!

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit2/RequestFactoryTest.java. Check getWithEncodedQueryParamMap run the test yourself. Nothing wrong default encoded = false shoudl work in almost all cases